# Jquery tools min Conflict error

Tags: jquery

I have got the following error while using tabs in html page.
"cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined". I get this error when i include 
jquery.tools.min.js plugin. But for my application  tools.min.js is required. Anyone please suggest a suitable solution for this error. Thanks in advance.
i have mentioned the order of plugin in the following

```
<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="script/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think there are 2 versions of `jQuery`. Can you try removing the first one you included?

Comment: I think `jquery.tools.min.js` already exposes the `jQuery` global for you. So you can try remove the `jquery.min` and try?

Comment: Try to put <script src="script/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> at first position